# Where are *.ofs files stored?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I would like to customize an Outlook appointment form.

Reading this [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx#UsingFormRegionDesignedOutlook) I see that I can import 
TaskFormRegion.ofs and work on it.
But where are these ofs files are located?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create it in Outlook first. See [Video How to: Designing an Outlook Form Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837160(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information.

Be aware, you can create a form region in Visual Studio without importing .ofs files. See [Walkthrough: Designing an Outlook Form Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157865.aspx).